# django urlpattern path argument empty (' ') meaning?

Tags: python, django

I am linking a views to urls.py inside the app.
Django docs show it like this

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Note: This urls.py is from app not the project, I have already directed the project(from urls.py) to this file.

I want to ask what does path('') means, the first argument of path. What kind of urlpattern is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that '/' or '' path in the URL will match this view for example if you are in dev environment you will be able to see the `index` view using the following urls:
`http://localhost:8000` or `http://localhost:8000/` both urls will match the `index` view.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you are using localhost.
When you use empty argument for path in app's url.
This path url used to call index function from views.py

In the giving case, after writing localhost:8000 you add projects url path. then you will just leave empty. It calls index function.

e.g. localhost:8000/projects_url_path/